# Error trying to connect to Azure SQL DB using Azure Query Editor (preview)...firewall settings already made

Tags: azure

I have been searching for an answer on this one most of the day.  I am working to deploy an Azure SQL database.  I have followed a tutorial to create a new DB along with the associated resource group and server.  I then followed an additional tutorial to add both my local desktop IP and turn on "Allow Azure Services" in the SQL server's firewall.  When I try to connect with the Azure Query Editor (preview) it tries for about 20 seconds and then I get an error "A connection to the server 'myserver.database.windows.net' could not be established. This may indicate an issue with your network connection or firewall configuration. Please check your network connection and try again."  I have double and triple checked the firewall settings and since I am using an Azure Query Editor I wouldn't think my local computer's firewall would be causing any issues but just in case I tried turning off all my local firewall and antivirus, no difference.  As an aside I also cannot connect using SSMS but I know that adds additional client-side issues so I would be happy for now just to have Query Editor work.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

slimmorama

Answer (score 0):

After much messing around I found 2 issues that were causing my problem:

1. I had opened the SQL ports in my Windows firewall but it turns out they were also being blocked by my ISP router firewall, after fixing that I got a different error, which was fixed by...
2. It turns out I have a dynamic IP so every so often I need to check and replace the "allow my local IP" setting in the Azure firewall rules to account for the changed IP.

After fixing both of these I was finally successful in using both Azure Query Editor AND SSMS from my local machine to access the Azure SQL DB.

slimmorama